# How to implement query function to use Google spreadsheet as a database?

Tags: javascript, database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use a spreadsheet as a database, where each sheet would be a table and the name of a person is used as a primary key (It seems not to be the best solution, but the good spreadsheet interface makes me prefer this solution rather than trying to use ScriptDB.)
And I want to do the following: When you select a name on a sheet and press a button on the menu I added, a function performs a search in another table and a screen and shows all the results of that query in the other table, showing properties records that only that table contains (later I want to add the possibility to generate a text file from a GDocs template).
My questions is:
1) Considering this screen/panel UI has a variable length (because the record number may vary in other tables), what is the best way to create this panel/UI in Google Apps Script? (I don't want to use the Logger.log because I want to add a button to convert the query into a file)

2) In addition to this solution (a search in the resulting 2D array):

```
function test(){ // to test the find function with an argument, 'any' in this case 
  var result = findItem('any');
  if(result){Logger.log(result.getA1Notation())}else{Logger.log('no luck !')};
}

function findItem(item){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues()
  for(var n = 0;n<data.length;++n){
    if(data[n].indexOf(item)>-1){ // this is a "strict" find, ie the value must be the entire search item. If you want to do partial match you should compare differently...
      return (ss.getRange(n+1,data[n].indexOf(item)+1)); // if found return the range. note the +1 because sheets have 1 index while arrays have 0 index
    }
  }
  return false;// if we come to the end of sheet without result...
}
```

There is an alternative method to perform queries like this?

THANKS for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UI instance.  Then a scrollable panel inside a main panel is the best way of doing this and then using array's to search through the data. I typically create header body and footer panels with the body being scrollable